# How do I make Vite build my files every time a change is made?

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm trying to make Vite build my files and output them into the `dist` folder every time I save/make changes on to my files during development.

How would I do that?

Here is my `vite.config.development.js` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
export default defineConfig({
    base: "./",
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: "assets/[name].[ext]",
                chunkFileNames: "assets/[name].[ext]",
                entryFileNames: "assets/[name].js",
            },
        },
        write: true,
    },
});
```

Here is my scripts in `package.json`:

```
"frontend-dev": "vite --config vite.config.development.js",
```

It does the usual `localhost:3000` thing, but it does not build my files and put them in the `dist` folder when I make changes to my source code.

Currently, I have to run a `vite build` npm script every time which takes a lot of time.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to see the development files everytime you make a change on the filesystem?

Comment: @RahilWazir yeah, I have an express server that serves static files from the build folder 'dist', so everytime I make a change during development, I want to build the new files to the dist folder so my express server can get the new updated build files

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want Vite to do a [rebuild on file changes](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#rebuild-on-files-changes), you can use the [`--watch` flag](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#rebuild-on-files-changes):

```
vite build --watch
```

In your case, with a custom config file:

```
vite build --watch --config vite.config.development.js
```

With the `--watch` flag enabled, changes to the config file, as well as any files to be bundled, will trigger a rebuild and will update the files in `dist`.

Comment: is there a way to do this for the `vite dev` command? --watch isn't a valid flag and I have to send an API request every time I make a change to trigger a rebuild.

Comment: In dev Vite does not trigger a build, so it wouldn't make sense to use `--watch`.

Perhaps you can leverage the [HMR API](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-hmr.html#hmr-api) to perform an action on changes, or use a plugin like [`vite-plugin-run`](https://github.com/innocenzi/vite-plugin-run).

Comment: Is there a way to configure this to work on the public dir?

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Mussini's answer, you have a few options:

1. Add `--watch` and optional `--config`:  `vite build --watch --config vite.config.ts` on cli
2. Add to package.json:

   ```
   {
     "name": "frontend",
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "dev": "vite",
       ...
       "build-watch": "vite build --watch --config ./vite.config.js",
       "build": "vite build",
   ```
3. Integrate `--watch` into the vite.config.ts which adds watching to the build cmd by default (`vite build` does not exit!)

   ```
   export default defineConfig({
     build: {
       watch: './vite.config.js',
   ```

   You likely want option 2 and use with `npm run build-watch`

Answer (score -4):

Do you know NodeJS? If you know NodeJS, you can monitor folders and files with the fs module. By monitoring the src directory, you can trigger the vite whenever there is a change. This is the manual solution. I don't know if there are currently npm packages that provide this.

[NodeJS Filestream Watch](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener)